# emphasis and not emphasis in the same word

Tags: restructuredtext

In ReStructuredText, is it possible to have emphasis and no emphasis in the same word? For example:

```
*emph*not-emph
```

leading to "*emph* no-emph", but with no white space in between? I can't find a way to do it, not even with a substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Character-Level Inline Markup](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup). The description from the reStructuredText specification is (emphasis mine):

> It is possible to mark up individual characters within a word with backslash escapes [...] **Backslash escapes can be used to allow arbitrary text to immediately follow inline markup.**

The two examples provided in the specification are:

1. For a single character immediately following inline markup:

   ```
    Python ``list``\s use square bracket syntax.
   ```
2. For arbitrary text immediately following inline markup:

   ```
    Possible in *re*\ ``Structured``\ *Text*, though not encouraged.
   ```

So to achieve the output you want, you need to use the backslash-escaped whitespace pattern:

```
*emph*\ not-emph
```

The reason this is required is because the [inline markup recognition rules](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup-recognition-rules) require that:

> Inline markup end-strings must end a text block or be immediately followed by
>
> - whitespace,
> - one of the ASCII characters - . , : ; ! ? \ / ' " ) ] } > or
> - a non-ASCII punctuation character with Unicode category *Pd* (Dash), *Po* (Other), *Pe* (Close), *Pf* (Final quote), or *Pi* (Initial quote).

Note that the use of that pattern above is discouraged in the reStructuredText specification:

> The use of backslash-escapes for character-level inline markup is not encouraged. Such use is ugly and detrimental to the unprocessed document's readability. Please use this feature sparingly and only where absolutely necessary.